# How do you remove an add-in link in outlook signature

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-signature

In my signature i have the business address and it is fine while working in outlook, but once it is sent the business address turns blue and has a dashed underline. When you put the mouse over it it has a pop up box saying "click or tap to open add-in" and it takes you to bing maps. How do i remove this?? It just started doing this and no setting have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a Bing Add-in installed trying to be helpful. Its probably being triggered by something in the content rather than something thats changed.

Try this:  Open Outlook, open the file menu and click "Manage Add-ins", in the webpage that opens, untick `Bing Maps`. Once its saved, close browser and restart outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Just as MisterSmith said, there could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and see if the issue continues.

If it works fine in safe mode, then the problem is likely with one of your add-ins. You'll need to disable all add-ins after restarting Outlook in normal mode, and then enable them one by one to figure out the problematic one.